# Timeout waiting for kernel_info_reply at restarting kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, timeout, kernel

Good afternoon!

I just started using jupyter notebook today and weirdly get the error "Timeout waiting for kernel_info_reply" very  irregularly when I try to restart the kernel. I installed it over and use it in PyCharm Prof. This is the version:

```
jupyter --version  

IPython          : 7.28.0
ipykernel        : 6.4.2
ipywidgets       : 7.6.5
jupyter_client   : 7.0.6
jupyter_core     : 4.8.1
jupyter_server   : not installed
jupyterlab       : not installed
nbclient         : 0.5.4
nbconvert        : 6.2.0
nbformat         : 5.1.3
notebook         : 6.4.5
qtconsole        : 5.1.1
traitlets        : 5.1.1
```

The occurrence of the error varies from right before the "Kernel restarted", "Kernel shutdown" or "Kernel started" feedback and is stuck there:

```
[I 17:51:47.918 NotebookApp] Kernel restarted: 8b9d9fd4-b482-44fa-aff5-2be54ed04f79
[W 17:51:48.121 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info_reply: 01c47488-55f5-423b-9694-eec0b0b20feb
[I 17:51:48.350 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for 8b9d9fd4-b482-44fa-aff5-2be54ed04f79:1e9f14dc-770f4df19bc105a5f1138917
[I 17:51:48.356 NotebookApp] Kernel shutdown: 8b9d9fd4-b482-44fa-aff5-2be54ed04f79
[I 17:51:48.357 NotebookApp] 302 GET /api/kernelspecs/ (127.0.0.1) 0.340000ms
[W 17:52:48.350 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info_reply: 8b9d9fd4-b482-44fa-aff5-2be54ed04f79
```

When I press restart kernel again I get this Exception:

```
[E 17:57:19.272 NotebookApp] Exception restarting kernel
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/ana/PycharmProjects/thesis/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 89, in post
        yield maybe_future(km.restart_kernel(kernel_id))
      File "/Users/ana/PycharmProjects/thesis/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "/Users/ana/PycharmProjects/thesis/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 313, in restart_kernel
        self._check_kernel_id(kernel_id)
      File "/Users/ana/PycharmProjects/thesis/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 394, in _check_kernel_id
        raise web.HTTPError(404, u'Kernel does not exist: %s' % kernel_id)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: 8b9d9fd4-b482-44fa-aff5-2be54ed04f79)
[E 17:57:19.272 NotebookApp] {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "Authorization": "Token e7075ff828aad3913497d5396e75ae2e1fa9d9b775ba68cc",
      "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
      "User-Agent": "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.12)",
      "Cookie": "username-localhost-8888=2|1:0|10:1635263508|23:username-localhost-8888|44:MDNiYmQyNWRmNzZhNDQzM2JjOWJkOGZmYjE3NDM5N2Y=|294d2a7c780f82308ad65278779201a1c52959e9e31234fe6db5e02b3f2cb492",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate"
    }
[E 17:57:19.273 NotebookApp] 500 POST /api/kernels/8b9d9fd4-b482-44fa-aff5-2be54ed04f79/restart (127.0.0.1) 1.820000ms referer=None
[W 17:57:19.277 NotebookApp] 404 DELETE /api/sessions/da222525-ff9d-412d-82b2-f5c8225e5e05 (127.0.0.1): Session not found: session_id='da222525-ff9d-412d-82b2-f5c8225e5e05'
[W 17:57:19.277 NotebookApp] Session not found: session_id='da222525-ff9d-412d-82b2-f5c8225e5e05'
[W 17:57:19.277 NotebookApp] 404 DELETE /api/sessions/da222525-ff9d-412d-82b2-f5c8225e5e05 (127.0.0.1) 1.470000ms referer=None
[I 17:57:19.279 NotebookApp] 302 GET /api/kernelspecs/ (127.0.0.1) 0.600000ms
[I 17:57:19.316 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 00dfbd03-5d6c-4ced-91e7-01c17214af77, name: python3
```

Other times I can restart the kernel quick and without errors.

There is no consistency of the occurrence of the error and how many cells I ran or how long I wait before restarting the kernel.

I could not reproduce the error when working directly in the browser, where everything ran smoothly.

Does anyone have an idea what might be the cause of this behaviour and why it is so different wether it runs locally or in the browser?
Shouldn't it be more consistent when running locally?

Cheers,
Ana